# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style') - rotate on scroll troubleshoot

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, rotation, typeerror

I'm trying to do a rotate-element-on-scroll effect but it seems my JS is wrong. I get the error "(index):271 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')"

My page is jakobnatorp.com

Edit: I've tried replacing "document.querySelector("logoJakob")" with following and it still doesn't work:

```
document.querySelector(".logoJakob");
document.querySelector("#jakoblogo");
document.getElementByClassName("logoJakob");
document.getElementById("jakoblogo");
```

HTML

```
<div class="logojakob" id="jakoblogo" >
<img src="http://jakobnatorp.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/cropped-JAKOB-LERCHE-DAA-NATORP.png"/>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.logojakob {
  position: fixed;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-bottom:-300px;
  margin-left:50px;
}
```

JS

```
var elem = document.querySelector("logoJakob");
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var value = window.scrollY * 0.25;
    elem.style.transform = `translatex(-50%) translatey(-50%) rotate(${value}deg)`; 
});
```

Comment: `document.querySelector("logoJakob")` won’t exist: you don’t have a `<logoJakob>` element.

Comment: It also doesn't work with document.getElementById("jakoblogo")

Comment: Is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `defer` attribute and no `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener and is not `type="module"`? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](/q/14028959/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

First selector is almost correct, there is only a missing dot and an extra uppercase in querySelector.
Pass the class to the querySelector exactly as it is written in CSS

```
var elem = document.querySelector(".logojakob");
```